# D3 timescale with date object returning NaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a Date object that I am passing to a D3 time scale:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, main_width-axis_offset]);

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
```

Then later on...

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
```

d.date is in the following format:

```
d.date = new Date(d.year, d.month-1, d.day);

Mon Jan 20 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Here is a fiddle link showing the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/goodspeedj/Ds9E6/

The docs state "Given a date x in the input domain, returns the corresponding value in the output range."

Is this expecting date in a different format?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the domains for x and y for `data`, but the real data is under `data.results`. If you change your code accordingly, everything works fine:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data.result, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data.result, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ds9E6/5/).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the domain for the scale, only the range.  E.g.:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, main_width-axis_offset]).domain([minDate, maxDate]);
```

The scale requires range and domain, because it maps one to the other.  So you should have the date you want to map to 0 in the x axis in place of "minDate", and the date you want to map to whatever value main_width-axis_offset is in place of "maxDate".

In the API doc: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-domain

Comment: I do have the domain set, I just didn't include it since it wasn't part of the problem (edited to include it).  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));